# TypeScript narrow generic function

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have a generic function

```
function hi<T>(name: T) { }
hi('Alex')
hi('Jim')
```

I would like to create a new function that would limit the generic type, and would allow only `Alex` as the `name`. Something like pseudo-code below

```
function hiAlex = hi<'Alex'>
hiAlex('Alex') // works well
hiAlex('Jim')  // ERROR wrong name type
```

Comment: Good overview of input validation https://medium.com/@gigobyte/custom-type-errors-and-input-validation-in-typescript-2-8-bca4fa6b2940

Answer (score 3):

There is no dedicated syntax for this unfortunately. The best we can do is repeat the signature as it would be instantiated by the call:

```
function hi<T>(name: T) { }
const hiAlex: (name: "Alex") => void = hi;

hiAlex('Alex') // works well
hiAlex('Jim')  // ERROR wrong name type
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function hi<T>(name: T extends string ? 'Alex' : T) { }
hi('Alex')
hi('Jim') // Argument of type '"Jim"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Alex"'
```

Something like this should work, if I understood your question correctly.

Or just don't make it a generic:

`function hi(name: 'Alex') { }`

Or

`function hi<T>(name: 'Alex') { }`